# Receber variavel tempo real ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Bem eu estou fazendo um sistema, e preciso de receber a variável de uma pagina php a cada momento, para que possa trabalhar nela na minha pagina index.php.

Um amigo meu que entende mais de ajax do que eu me passou o seguinte código:

Contudo, eu não sei como faço para passar os valores da variável x no PHP (*loading.php*), para o meu JavaScript na pagina `index.php`.

O Código da minha página index.php é assim:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get("loading.php", function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como poderei fazer?

Comment: A página PHP `loading.php` tem de ter algures `echo 'Alguma coisa...';` e assim o ajax apanha essa string e envia para a callback. Sabes como fazer isso?

Comment: De PHP, eu etendo muito, então diz me uma coisa, se quiser receber 2 variaveis em vez de uma, faria echo 2x das 2 variaveis, mas depois como recebia elas no javascript?

Comment: Nesse caso envia uma array ou um objeto. `echo json_encode(array('foo', 'bar'));`e no JavaScript: `JSON.parse(data);` ou usando um método do jQuery para JSON.

Comment: Poderias me dar um exemplo?, Sou um pouco novo nisto do ajax e de json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se queres passar vários valores sugiro enviares um JSON do PHP para o JavaScript.

O JSON é uma string de dados organizados e no PHP podes criar JSON de arrays ou objetos com `json_encode($aMinhaVariavel);`

Para fazer com que o AJAX possa apanhar esse dados tens de usar `echo`.

Assim no lado do PHP podes ter por exemplo assim:

```
$array = array('dados A', 'dados B');
echo json_encode($array);
```

No JavaScript podes usar o [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)  do jQuery que já converte a string de JSON.

E aí podes ter assim:

```
$.getJSON("loading.php", function(array) {
    alert(array[0]);
    alert(array[1]);
});
```

Comment: No caso, se quisesse passar esses dados do `array[0]` para uma variavel, poderia fazer da seguinte forma: `var goncalo = array[0];` é assim certo?

Comment: @Gonçalo exato.

Comment: Consegui! Obrigado Sergio!

Comment: @Gonçalo ótimo. Fico contente de ter podido ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Bom aqui seria um exemplo de envio de dados por ajax

```
  $.ajax({
              var dado= "algumas coisa que queira enviar";
              url: "recebe.php",

              type: 'POST',

              data: dado,

              success: function (data) {
               $("body").html(data);



              }
            });
```

Ai no php que recebe esses dados, que no caso é o recebe.php, que recebe esses dados atraves do metodo POST, ficaria assim.

```
 <?php
    $DadoRecebido= $_POST['dado'];
    echo "deu certo";
?>
```

E o ajax ali escreveria no body "Deu certo", que é o echo que dei no php que recebeu os dados do ajax.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: No caso, eu queria receber os dados da página e não enviar! Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda, foi me muito grato e irei utilizar isto no futuro.